# Ordering Docs Snapshot By Time Firebase V9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I'm looking to order the docs that are received from Firestore from oldest to newest.
I'm using JS getTime() to set a field within the docs I'm trying to order and im using this code:

`onSnapshot(collection(db, 'guides'), orderBy('timeStamp'), (snapshot) => { console.log(snapshot.docs); });`

I feel like im doing everything right and have spend ages trying to figure this out.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'guides'), orderBy('timeStamp'));
onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data())); 
  });
});
```

Note that we pass only two parameters to `onSnapshot()` (including the callback) while you pass three.

Comment: Thank you, would not have gotten this on my own, its working now!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use for-loops, this may be a solution as well:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchMessages() {
      getDocs(
        query(collection(db, "messages"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc"))
      ).then((querySnapshot) => {
        setMessages(
          querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, message: doc.data() }))
        );
      });
    }
    fetchMessages();
  }, [input, setMessages]);
```