# how to get the snapshot of collection ( "message" ) by Descending order using "orderBy" method in firebase js v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

here i trying to get the collection("messages") snapshot which conatains document, but i want to get the collections snapshot which shoud be order by "timestamp" feild of documents in decending order how could i do that useing js v9 of firebase

```
onSnapshot(collection(db,"channels",channelId,"messages"),(snapshot) => {
  setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
})
```

Comment: You may refer to a similar [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377527/ordering-docs-snapshot-by-time-firebase-v9), which also mentions about ordering documents by timestamp in Firebase version 9. Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `query()` function to build a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query) and then `orderBy()` function to specify the [Query Constraint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.queryconstraint). Try the following:

```
import { collection, query, onSnapshot, orderBy } from "firebase/firestore"

const colRef = collection(db, "channels", channelId, "messages"), orderBy('timemstamp', 'desc'))

const q = query(colRef, orderBy("timestamp", "desc"))

onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
})
```